# Quartz, Quartz.Jobs and Quartz.AspNetCore Nuget Packages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, quartz.net

I'm trying to understand the differences between Quartz, Quartz.Jobs, and the Quartz.AspNetCore NuGet packages.

What does Quartz.Jobs provide that is not in the Quartz package, when should I use it and why?

The same question applies to Quartz.AspNetCore. What does it provide and when should I use it?

Answer (score 1):

Quartz.NET ("Quartz" on NuGet) and Quartz.AspNetCore are simply the same package, but for ASP.NET Framework and ASP.NET Core, respectively.

Quartz.Jobs is an ASP.NET Framework augmented version of Quartz that contains additional job scheduling features.

You can see this information in NuGet or in the code yourself by viewing the modules' dependencies.

Comment: Both packages (Quartz and Quartz.AspNetCore) seem to install and work with .net core (specifically testing on .NET 5). Both packages also point to https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/ for the project URL. Any advantages you know of for using one over the other?

Comment: Ah, nvm. I see now, IserviceCollection doesn't have a definition for AddQuartz when using Quartz.Net.

Comment: @eaglei22 Many .NET Framework libraries may work fine in .NET Core, but there is no guarantee unless stated (generally this is stated implicitly by releasing a .NET Core-specific version, even if none of the code has changed).

Comment: Makes sense, thanks!